# Access data connection won't work after publishing to server.

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010

I have a VB.net web application which should be connected to a MS Access Database.
I did the following to accomplish the connection:

-On Visual Studio: New Data connection;

-Selected "Microsoft ODBC Data Source" (tried the OLE DB option, but didn't get anything working);

-MS Access database, selected my database .accdb;

After linking this data to a gridview, I preview it on the web browser and it works perfectly. However after publishing my project to the server I get the following error message:

"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is there an ODBC connection on your workstation that's not on the server? (Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Data Sources)  Or is the .accdb in the app_data subdirectory and the publish settings say to exclude app_data?

Comment: The server is not located at the same country as I am, so I suppose that I don't have access to check if there is some ODBC connection on my PC that is not on the server, right? Also, I checked the publish settings and they are not excluding the app_data. Thanks

Comment: Don't use ODBC (in general) especially when sending your app to other computers/servers that you don't have full control over. To use ODBC, you would have to get on that server and manually setup the ODBC connection you are expecting. There are non-manual ways to do this but it takes a bit of work. Use the OLDB driver.